# How to prevent CKeditor from displaying blockquotes in italic?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there any way to globally remove the `font-style : italic` property of the blockquote tags displayed **inside** the form ?

This feature is very misleading for users.

Note : I am using CKeditor version 4.

Answer (score 1):

you can append a custom css file with the config option contentsCss, in your custom css just add:

blockquote { font-style: normal; }

check the working example at:

http://carlosquintero.name/example.html

**Note:** im using cdn and im loading default css from ckeditor too, you can just skype the ckeditor css file if you dont want have defined styles for the editor.

You can read more information from ckeditor documenation on the follow link:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I create a custom Css file with contentsCss option, it seems like I lose all the other styles... 
Maybe there is something that I can add in the configuration to prevent overwriting all existing styles by doing so.